# Как в PHP вернуть из функции тип класс, переданный туда в виде аргумента

Tags: php, laravel, типизация

В Laravel есть функция `app()`, которая принимает на вход путь до класса (например `app(MyClass::class)` и возвращает его экземпляр. Мне нужно написать такую же функцию. Условно это выглядит так:

```php
class MyClass {}

function app(string $path)
{
    return new $path();
}

app(MyClass::class) // должен вернуться объект класса MyClass
```

Проблема в том, что тип возвращаемого значения не определен (mixed). Соответственно никакие подсказки не работают, IDE начинает путаться и работать с такой функцией не комфортно. Однако у Laravel эта же функция возвращает объект того класс, который был передан ей в качестве параметра.

```php
// Laravel
app(MyClass::class) // тип MyClass
// Моя реализация
app(MyClass::class) // тип mixed, подсказки не работают
```

Если бы в php были дженерики, можно было бы сделать что-то типа:

```php
function app<T>(string $path): T
{
    return new $path();
}

app<MyClass::class>(MyClass::class);
```

но дженериков в php пока нет, а Laravel справляется и без них. Любая IDE понимает, что возвращаемый тип у функции тот же, что был передан ей в качестве параметра. Я смотрел способ через phpDocs, по типу `@psalm-return` и `@template`, но ничего из этого не сработало.

Соответственно вопрос: как создать функцию, которая будет так же типизировать возвращаемое значение на основе типа аргумента?

UPD:
По умолчанию типов для `app()` нет. С этим помогает ide-helper. Однако запускать команду генерации нужно лишь один раз, и все новые классы при подстановке в `app` будут из него возвращаться с правильным типом. Немного напутал про причину, но вопрос остаётся открытым: ведь ide-helper как-то смог реализовать нужное поведение

Comment: MyClass::class - это не строка

Comment: Какую IDE вы используете?

Comment: @yauhen-kib я проверял работу на phpStorm и в VSCode с включенным IntelliSense. Обе IDE показывали одинаковый результат: типы видны

Comment: @Виктор `echo gettype(MyClass::class)` => `string`

Comment: У меня например по умолчанию в phpStorm определение типа не срабатывает. Но если установить пакет barryvdn/laravel-ide-helper и выполнить команду php artisan ide-helper:meta, в корне генерируется вспомогательный файл и типизация работает. Попробуйте разобраться как он устроен...

Comment: @YauhenKib именно! Хотел сегодня апдейтнуть и забыл. Действительно все дело в ide-helper. При чем он работает не только для phpStorm а вообще для всех IDE. Я думал, что найду там ссылки на `app()` или `Application`, но это ничего не дало

Answer (score -1):

Можно указать тип возвращаемого функцией значения

```
function app(string $path): MyClass
    {
        return new $path();
    }
```

Comment: Класс должен подставляться динамически, в зависимости от пути, подставленного в аргумент. Хардкод типа не поможет